# Regular expression - how to negate ^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{2}$

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Regular expression - how to negate `^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{2}$`

Comment: Many tools offer negation like `grep -v`. In programming languages you can use something like `if(!match(str, pattern))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see demo here https://regex101.com/r/bO9pH0/2

```
/^(?![A-Z]{4}[0-9]{2}$).*/gm
```